# Name of short story in which a woman and an alien have sex because they're bored

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, sexuality

I remember reading a short science fiction story (which had maybe been nominated for an award) in which a woman and a blob-like alien have sex for what might be years; The second sentence or so in the story actually uses the word, 'fuck'.

Her spaceship had crashed into the alien's and somehow they'd both ended up in an escape pod with nothing to do but pass the time by having sex. In the end she finally makes it back to earth.

Know the name of the story and/or author?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Possibly Kij Johnson's ["Spar"](http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/johnson_10_09/), 2009 winner of the Nebula award, 2010 Hugo Award nominee, and 2010 Locus award finalist. That link provides an audio and text version, and is suggested by [the author's website](http://www.kijjohnson.com/read.html). You can find a list of works it's been in [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1043092). It is the first sentence, not the second.

> In the tiny lifeboat, she and the alien fuck endlessly, relentlessly.

....

> The alien is not humanoid. It is not bipedal. It has cilia. It has no bones, or perhaps it does and she cannot feel them. Its muscles, or what might be muscles, are rings and not strands. Its skin is the color of dusk and covered with a clear thin slime that tastes of snot. It makes no sounds. She thinks it smells like wet leaves in winter, but after a time she cannot remember that smell, or leaves, or winter.

Comment: Don't forget the hilarious ["makin' bacon" remix](https://clarkesworldmagazine.com/johnson_04_13_reprint/)